# Async lambda: "a task was cancelled"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, lambda, async-await

Here's the workflow:

1. Incoming HTTP request to WebApi2 endpoint.
2. Make synchronous (e.g. not async) call to get some data.
3. Map response from DB entity to API model.
   a. Executes AutoMapper mapping.
   b. Includes the following snippet (see below).
   c. If operation is "quick", no issue. If operation is "slow", then "a task was cancelled" exception is thrown.

I get lucky in cases when the mapping action is quick. But if I add a `Task.Delay(2000)`, then I get the exception in question. It seems that ASP.NET is not "waiting" for my async lamba to complete?

Here is the body of the mapping expression:

```
mapping.AfterMap(async (entity, model) => {
    var child = await _childRepo.Get(entity.ChildId);
    await Task.Delay(2000); // For testing, of course.
    if (child != null)
    {
        // Fill in some properties on model
    }
});
```

Note that this is example code, and I don't intend to make additional DB/repo calls during mapping in "real life".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`AfterMap` takes an `Action`](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/AutoMapper/5.1.1/netstandard1.3/doc/AutoMapper.IMappingExpression/AfterMap(System.Action(System.Object,System.Object))), which is a [synchronous delegate, not an asynchronous delegate](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/02/synchronous-and-asynchronous-delegate.html) (as I explain on my blog). As such, it does not work as expected with `async` lambdas.

In this case (since the delegate returns `void`), the compiler will actually allow an `async` lambda; however, it will compile to an `async void` method. (The compiler does this to allow `async` event handlers). As I describe in my MSDN article on async best practices, you should [avoid `async void`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

One of the reasons to avoid `async void` is that it is very difficult to detect when an `async void` method has completed. In fact, (with the exception of WebForm lifetime events), ASP.NET will not even attempt to do so.

Comment: In practice, making an event handler `async` doesn't appear to work (at least when I've tried it). It seems the compiler could be a little more strict about my use of an async lambda in a non-async context, or at least give me a warning? Thanks for the info.

Comment: @JoshM.: There are probably add-on analyzers that would catch this.